# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and image rotation

Tags: ios, ios4

my app has an image as background, if I rotate the device, all widgets and rotated, but not the background image.

My implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is straight forward:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Any hints?

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: Damned! I mean: the background-image gets rotated, but not scaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the image in a UIImageView if you want automatic scaling. But I suggest having two pictures properly sized for two different orientations and switch between them in code.

Comment: Ah ok, now I see the problem: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"karo_iphone.png"]]; Is there another method to set the backgroundcolor of the view without the pattern, but with correct scaling?